# Docker - start container with environments variables

Tags: mysql, docker

Is there any way to start an existing container with appended environment variables?

I would like to achieve something like when you press `Save` from `Kitematic`. Somehow in `Kitematic` the container restarts with the new settings (variables, ports, volumes).

If I run:

```
docker run -it -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test123" --name "mysql" mysql
```

I get the error:

> Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/mysql" is
>   already in use by container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop and remove it `docker stop mysql; docker rm mysql` and retry

Answer (score 2):

You can not change environment variables and port forwardings for the already created container. Because *docker start* does not have necessary options.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/